# How to allow a user to download a Google Cloud Storage file from Compute Engine without public access

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm going to try and keep this as short as possible.

I have a compute engine instance, and it is running Python/Flask.

What I am trying to do, is allow a user to download a file from google cloud storage, however I do not want the file to be publicly accessible. Is there a way I can have my Compute instance stream the file from cloud storage for the user to download, and then have the file deleted from the compute instance after the user has finished downloading the file? I'd like the download to start immediately after they click the download button.

I am using the default app credentials.
subprocess is not an option.

SideNote:
Another way I was thinking about doing this was to allow each user, who is logged into the website, access to a specific folder on a bucket. However I am unsure if this would even be possible without having them login with a google account. This also seems like it would be a pain to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jterrace's answer is what you want.

Signed URLs can have a time limit associated with them.  In your application you would create a signed url for the file and do a HTTP redirect to said file.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program

If you are using the default compute engine service account (the default associated with your GCE instance) you should be able to sign just fine.  Just follow the instructions on how to create the keys in the url above.

You can do all kinds of awesome stuff this way, including allowing users to upload DIRECTLY to google cloud storage! :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

Answer (score 0):

**Service account** associated with your compute engine will solve the problem.

> [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) authenticate applications running on your
>   virtual machine instances to other Google Cloud Platform services. For
>   example, if you write an application that reads and writes files on
>   Google Cloud Storage, it must first authenticate to the Google Cloud
>   Storage API. You can create a service account and grant the service
>   account access to the Cloud Storage API.

For historical reasons, all projects come with the Compute Engine default service account, identifiable using this email:

```
[PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

By default, the service account of compute engine has read-only access to google cloud storage service. So, compute engine can access your storage using GCP client libraries.

[gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) is the command-line tool for GCP storage, which is very handy for trying out various options offered by storage.

start by typing `gsutil ls` from your compute engine which lists all the buckets in your cloud storage.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I understand this. I actually already have access via the default credentials as I had mentioned. What I am trying to do, is allow a user to download from the bucket, without making the files publicly accessible. So I suppose what I am looking for, is an example where compute engine downloads the file, and streams that file to the user after they click a download button. Once the download has finished on the users end, compute engine deletes the downloaded file, but it should stay in cloud storage.

Comment: The question is not brief. It is more like a mini project. Try fast prototyping and if you break somewhere, post the source code where you get the trouble, and developers in stack overflow would be able to help you. Add you need an example to your question